# Github actions: Re-usable workflows

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

So what I am trying to do is to organize my ci workflow. I have a self-hosted runner that is my personal computer. Since the  workflow files is getting too large I am thinking about reducing the size by having different workflow files instead.

so this is my files so far:

```
name: "Pipeline"
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} just pushed.
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 2 * * *"
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - "docs/*"
    tags:
      - "v*"
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      cc_platform:
        description: "Input of branch name to build metalayers."
        required: true
        default: "dev"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    name: Build job.
    steps:
      - name: Checking out the repository.
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Settings Credentials.
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.6.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY_CC }}

      - name: Creating config file.
        run: 
          touch conf

      - name: Removing old folders & running build script.
        run: |
          if [[ -d "my_folder" ]]; then rm -rf my_folder; fi
          ./build

      - name: Generate a zip file of artifacts.
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
          with:
            name: art_${{ github.sha }}
            path: |
              .*.rootfs.wic.xz
              .*.rootfs.manifest
            if-no-files-found: error
```

so what I want to do it to have the artifacts and the build step in their own workflow file. But it does give me som concersn.

1. Will each workflow file get run in their own runner?
2. Do they share memory?